# Unable to recover a full image using java bufferwriter?

Tags: java, image

From Input Stream i am reading the image data and convert it to string. From string am writing to an image directly by following type.

```
final BufferedReader reader = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(in));
final char[] cbuf = new char[1024];
final int length = reader.read(cbuf);

String packet=new String(cbuf,0,length);
BufferedWriter out = null ;
FileWriter fstream ;
File file = new File(fileName);
fstream = new FileWriter(file);
out.write(packet);
```

Please guide me in this issue.
I am not getting full image. [image]

Comment: What do you mean _convert to string_?

Comment: an image is binary data, and therefore some of it will not be able to be converted to a string.  try using a byte array

Comment: that also i tried. @ScaryWombat

Comment: you are also only reading the first 1024 chars.  You should loop around until `read` == -1

Comment: Also `out` is not initialised.

Comment: @ScaryWombat OP still gets something as output, so probably initialization was omitted.

Comment: @Basilevs I am hoping so.

Answer (score 0):

```
final BufferedReader reader = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(in));
```

[Decodes input](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/io/InputStreamReader.html#InputStreamReader(java.io.InputStream)) using default encoding potentially corrupting data.

```
out.write(packet);
```

Encodes characters using default encoding potentially corrupting data.

Read documentation on API you use. Only perform conversion with default or unknown encoding when you absolutely need it.

[Read/convert an InputStream to a String](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/309424/read-convert-an-inputstream-to-a-string)

Comment: wrong method.  He is using String(char[] value, int offset, int count)

Comment: @Basilevs i read upto end of the image and write it together. But still am getting like above image. verified check sum also. No idea ..

Comment: how big is your image? bigger than 1024 bytes?

Comment: If checksum is the same for original file,  this is no longer java question.

Comment: approximately 10KB to 20KB. Also am reading upto an end of the packet. Lenght of an image and checksum also matched finally. But final image was like this only.. @ScaryWombat

Comment: I guess that I am mis-reading your code then.  It does not show any looping to the end of a fileinputstream.